# Where are the logs of fsck done via the recovery mode at?

Tags: 16.04, recovery-mode, fsck

All I see is logs for pre-boot `fsck`, but not forced `fsck` via the `fsck` option in the recovery menu.

This is not a duplicate of [Where are fsck results logged at boot time, after /forcefsck?](/q/112907). It mentions pre-boot `fsck`, not this situation where I go into recovery mode to initiate a `fsck` manually. I use Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, so any solutions that apply to upstart won't help either.

Comment: I wonder if you will find them in /var/log/upstart as suggested by [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/603027/527764)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Not exactly, I can find fsck results logged at boot time fine, just find any instances of fsck in syslog. It doesn't seem to record fsck executions though forced via the recovery menu. As a result, it's not a duplicate. ;)

Comment: @Zanna Nope, not there either, but I don't use upstart anyways, just systemd, I use 16.04. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Zanna but yeah systemd is the default in Ubuntu since... 15.04. Just want to clarify that it wasn't my full intention to have systemd.

Comment: Indeed... So a second round of idle speculation... Could it be in journalctl ?

Comment: @Zanna where and how?

Comment: er by default `journalctl` doesn't get logged (if you type `journalctl` it just gives you info from current boot like `dmesg`) but according to [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs) you can make it persistent just by making a directory for the log! `sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal` or by editing `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` (sorry this isn't helping at all find past forced fsck data even if it works for future forced fsck!)

Comment: crap, oh well. Maybe I can use my boot-done fscks as proof that things were fine after all, as I found out.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any, if there is filesystem damage at boot, there won't be any filesystem mounted to write the log in yet.  Writing a log can make any damage worse.