# fsck force not doing its job?

Tags: partitioning, fsck

I want to check my filesystem. It has to be unmounted, so I found that I should

```
$ sudo touch /forcefsck
$ reboot
```

I did that on `Sat Dec 30 10:02 2017` (approx.)
After rebooting, this is what I get (pasting only the relevant info)

My partitions:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot Id Type
/dev/sda2  *    83 Linux
/dev/sda3        5 Extended
/dev/sda4       83 Linux
/dev/sda5       82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       83 Linux
/dev/sda7       83 Linux
```

Where is each one mounted (could have used other commands, I know):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem   Mounted on
/dev/sda6    /
/dev/sda4    /mnt/old-home
/dev/sda7    /home
/dev/sda2    /boot
```

Last time each parittion was checked:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | grep -i check
Last checked:             Sat Dec 30 10:02:48 2017
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda4 | grep -i check
Last checked:             Thu Nov  3 17:39:51 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep -i check
Last checked:             Fri Nov  4 12:08:31 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda7 | grep -i check
Last checked:             Sat Dec 30 10:02:04 2017
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
```

I expected `/dev/sda6` (i.e., `/`) to be checked, but it was not.

**Is that correct?**

**What is the correct way to check `/`? I think I am currently unable to boot from a Live CD/USB.**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the *Maximum mount count* to `1` and reboot which should start the `fsck`.

Before doing so, note down the default value you get with the command as follows. In the following example we will use `/dev/sda6` as an example.

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep 'Maximum mount count'
```

Then set the value to `1`.

```
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda6
```

Then reboot and the filesystem check should start.

Comment: I did this, and then 
`$ sudo touch /forcefsck`
`$ reboot`.
 I cannot find evidence that `/` was checked. E.g., referring to https://askubuntu.com/questions/112907/where-are-fsck-results-logged-at-boot-time-after-forcefsck, I tried `journalctl -b --no-pager | grep systemd-fsck` and `cat  /var/log/boot.log`. Both report having checked `/dev/sda2`and `/dev/sda7`, but not `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: What is the timestamp reported with `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep -i check`?

Comment: It reports `Last checked:             Wed Jan  3 06:38:19 2018`. So it seems to have checked `/dev/sda6`. If so, why the difference with `journalctl ...` and `/var/log/boot.log`?