# How to S.M.A.R.T. check root partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, smart

My root partition seems to be getting corrupted often. It's the second time this week. I would like to see the S.M.A.R.T. stats for the whole drive, but I am able to do it only for all the non-root disks (whilst using the Disks Utility).
How can I do a S.M.A.R.T. check on the whole drive?

Comment: When you're looking at SMART data, you are looking at the entire drive. Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu partition? Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: yes, I had to use ```fsck``` to fix my hdd - Ubuntu made me do it last time. It seems to be corrupted also currently, but I am still running it. On next restart, I am sure it will force fsck again, because my Chrome user files are already broken. There are a bunch of broken sectors.        
This is an issue unrelated to the question. I would like to see the SMART data from within Ubuntu to learn whether this is a software or a hardware issue.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about dual-boot, If you do, have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: Related: [Where are `fsck` results logged at boot time, after `/forcefsck`?](https://askubuntu.com/q/112907/349837)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the result of the most recent self-test through the gnome disks utility (run `sudo gnome-disks` from the CLI). To run a new test on the root disk, you'll need to run the test from a [live USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0).

Comment: This was my method of inspection already, prior to your suggestion (gnome-disk without sudo). The S.M.A.R.T. option is greyed out for the root partition though. Is that normal? It is a USB HDD.

Comment: @jeyko, **It works for me (without `sudo`)**. I tested right now from my USB SSD with Lubuntu 18.04 (installed system). But if you want to run a program with a graphical user interface, you should use `sudo -H GUI-program`, because plain `sudo` might damage your user's configuration files. -- See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983?r=SearchResults&s=3|14.2471#972983)

Comment: It is greyed out for me on Ubuntu 18.10 (system-disk external SSD). In the end I used a Live USB to do a SMART inspection and the outcome is that the disk is damaged.                  
            
Maybe edit the answer about ``sudo GUI``` so people don't damage their configs? I am not able to run the command.

Comment: An external SSD might not be SMART enabled in the first place; it's uncommon for internal drives not to have it but external drives might not conform to that standard. Check the manufacturer's website/FAQ